# Blender fluid basics: how to create water

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I’m a beginner at blender physics and I’d like to create add in an empty cube container some water, but I haven’t found yet a good tutorial about blender fluid physics. Can anyone redirect me to a good tutorial or briefly explain me water and fluids in blender?
I also haven’t found this question in blender stack exchange but if someone already asked it please redirect me to it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Plenty of online video tutorials. For Blender 3.2 try: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+fluid+simulation+3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you start Blender choose object -> quick effects -> quick liquid

[image]

in the domain check "mesh"

[image]

raise resolution to 128

[image]

change render engine to cycles

Choose an HDRI as lighting

and you will get already a pretty nice water animation.

But honestly: search on google for "Blender water animation" and you will find hundreds of free tutorials ....